# Cascading Parameters- No value option for child parameter

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix

I am an SSRS report where I have 6 cascading parameters.

- ProgramType.PMT_ID=@Program
- Scorecard_Scorecard_Profile.Scoredcard_ID=@Scorecard
- Scorecard_MF_Measures.Section_ID=@Scetion
- Scorecard_USER_Measure_Description.Measure_ID=@ Measure
- Scorecard_Measure_Component.Measure_Comp_ID=@ Component
- Scorecard_Measure_Sub_Component.Sub_Comp_ID=@Subcomponent

My supervisor typically wants to run the report at either the component or subcomponent level. I have not figured out a way to provide "no value" at the subcomponent level and still be able to run the report.

How do I write a query in the tablix dataset where the end-user can choose no value in the subcomponent parameter?

Thanks,
Stephanie

Answer (score 0):

When having an optional parameter, I usually add an OR for that in the SQL to check for a NULL value.

```
AND
(
Scorecard_Measure_Sub_Component.Sub_Comp_ID = @Subcomponent
OR
@Subcomponent IS NULL
)
```